# Как Изменить Текст в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

Никак не могу изменить текст в Unity,
Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class show : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text mytext;
    private scoreS scr;
    public List<string> nomen;
    private string test;
    private scoreS id;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mytext = GetComponent<Text>(); // получаем компонент Text на текущем объекте
        nomen = new List<string> {"Чёрное Море", "Баренцево море", "Карское море", "Азовское море", "Балтийское море", "Каспийское море", "Финский залив", "Рижский залив", "Калининградский залив", "Онежская губа", "Кандалакшский залив", "Двинская губа", "Мезенская губа", "Чешская губа", "Печорская губа", "Таганрогский залив", "Керченский пролив", "пролив Югорский шар", "пролив Карские ворота", "пролив Маточкин шар", "архипелаг Земля Франца-Иосифа", "архипелаг Новая Земля", "остров Колгуев", "остров Вайгач", "Соловецкие острова", "Тюлений остров", "Кольский полуостров", "полуостров Канин", "Югорский полуостров", "Рыбачий полуостров", "Хибины горы", "Уральские горы", "Кавказский горный хребет", "возвышенность Пай-хой", "Тиманский кряж", "возвышенность Северные увалы", "Валдайскую возвышенность", "Смоленско-Московскую возвышенность", "Среднерусскую возвышенность", "Приволжскую возвышенность", "возвышенность Общий Сырт", "Бугульминско-Белебевскую возвышенность", "Ставропольскую возвышенность", "Прикаспийскую низменность", "Кумо-Манычскую низменность", "реку Онегу", "реку Северную Двину", "реку Печору", "Реку Мезень", "реку Волгу", "реку Москву", "реку Оку", "реку Кострому", "реку Унжа", "реку Ветлугу", "реку Вятку", "реку Суру", "реку Днепр", "реку Западную двину", "реку Десна", "реку Воронеж", "реку Дон", "реку Кубань", "реку Кума", "реку Терек", "озеро Иманда", "озеро Ладожское", "озеро Онежское", "озеро Ильмень", "озеро Селигер", "озёра Чудское и Псковское", "озеро Белое", "озёра Эльтон и Баскунчак", "Рыбинское водохранилище", "Костромское водохранилище", "Горьковское водохранилище", "Чебоксарское водохранилище","Куйбышевское водохранилище", "Саратовское водохранилище", "Волгоградское водохранилище", "Цимлянское водохранилище", "Нижнекамское водохранилище", "Камское водохранилище", "Валузское водохранилище" };
        mytext.text = "Покажите" + nomen[id.rightAns];//берёт ответ, который нужно спросить из другого скрипта
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        mytext.text = "Покажите" + nomen[id.rightAns];
    }
}
```

Я новичок, что бы я не делал, выдаёт ошибку-
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Он не знает ни что такое scr, ни что такое id, поскольку ты не указал, кто они такие.
Сделать их public и указать в инспекторе.